# MVC Razor Validation Errors showing on page load when no data has been posted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm messing around with data annotations. When I click on a link to go to a page, the validation messages are being displayed, but I would like to have the validation messages not show unless data has been posted.

View:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder = "Enter Email", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Registration Failed. Check your credentials")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "You must enter a valid Email Address.")
```

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email Address: ")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddUser()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddUser(UserCreateViewModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var success = UserRepository.AddUser(user);

                if (success)
                {
                    return View("Success");
                }
            }

            return View("AddUser");
        }
```

Like I said, my problem occurs on page load of the AddUser view. When I click on the link to view the AddUser page, validation messages are showing after it loads, yet at this point no data has been posted and the model is empty.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the validation style to:

```
.validation-summary-valid { display:none; }
```

So by default it's hidden. An error will trigger it to display.

Comment: I was using a custom CSS file and had stop including the old Site.css reincluding this (which had your above fix) fixed my problem.

Comment: Why on earth we need to do it manually. Why it's not handled by the framework itself. :-|

Comment: This is most likely because the default Site.css was changed or is missing.

Answer (score 50):

You can clear model state after binding user:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

This happens because `ModelBinder` will set `ModelState` on binding.
In every action that binds a model and returns a view with the same model you will have this problem.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(UserCreateViewModel user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var success = UserRepository.AddUser(user);

        if (success)
        {
            return View("Success");
        }
    }

    ModelState.Clear(); // <-------
    return View("AddUser");
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful for me. I added ModelState.Clear() it's hide !!

Comment: Good one buddy (y)

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this will only happen for GET requests if the action receives an object with data annotations (as opposed to having arguments corresponding to the properties that were needed or an entirely different class w/o data annotations)

Comment: it also seems to happen when the controller GET action has a parameter, with the same name as a property in the model

Answer (score 2):

```
.field-validation-valid {
  display: none;
}
```

Whenever the validation triggers on page load, this ".field-validation-valid" value is automatically added to the class attribute of the triggered input element.

By adding CSS to display none as that particular class's value, you'll no longer see the validation messages on initial page load.

The validation messages will still display normally after the particular input element has been touched.

Comment: Care to explain how this answers OP's question?

Comment: This doesn't help the OP, but it helped me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Me too. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`$('.field-validation-error').html("");`